# Reference Assignment in Python - Why isn't the value changed?

Tags: python

I know that "variable assignment" in python is, in fact, a binding / re-binding of a name (the variable) to an object.

```
b = [1,2,3]
a = b[2] # binding a to b[2] ?
a = 1000
```

b is `[1, 2, 3]`

after this change,  why b is not changed?

here is another example:

```
b = [1,2,3]
a = b
a[0] = 1000
```

this case b is `[1000, 2, 3]`

isn't assignment in Python reference binding?

Thank you

Comment: `1,2,3` are constance not can change the value, but list its an object then when you assign `b` to `a` b you are creating a reference to b called `a` another words it same that a pointer to, then a is same b if you mutate one mute the reference "the memory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = b[2] # binding a to b[2] ?
```

Specifically, this binds the **name** `a` to the same **value** referenced by `b[2]`. It does not bind `a` to the element in the list `b` at index `2`. The name `a` is entirely independent of the list where it got its value from.

```
a = 1000
```

Now you bind the name `a` to a new value, the integer `1000`. Since `a` has no association with `b`, `b` does not change.

In your second example:

```
a = b
```

Now `a` is bound to the same list value that `b` is bound to. So when you do

```
a[0] = 1000
```

You modify an element in the underlying list that has two different names. When you access the list by either name, you will see the same value.

Answer (score 1):

`a[0] = ...` is a special form of assignment that desugars to a method call,

```
a.__setattr__(0, ...)
```

You aren't reassigning to the name `a`; you are assigning to a "slot" in the object referenced *by* `a` (and `b`).

Answer (score -2):

Lists are mutable objects, ints aren't. 4 can't become 5 in python, but a list can change its contents.